# Wordpress Post option not showing

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with my wordpress, after install ACF plugin post options is not showing, I deleted this plugin and I still don't see Category option and I can't check featured image [image]
Anybody can help me?

Comment: "Post Options" isn't something that WP or ACF uses to define a widget in this view. What _specifically_ is missing?

Comment: Category, post type, and featured Image

Answer (score 0):

Do you back up? Have you made any other changes that would be too difficult to recreate since your last backup? If possible, I think the easiest fix would be to revert to your backup. And if you aren't backing up, download a plugin for that asap. I use Backup Guard (https://backup-guard.com/products/backup-wordpress).

Comment: I don't have backup :(